# Using overbrace with parbox in equations

Tags: beamer, align, parbox, overbrace

I'm trying to use overbrace with parbox in an equation, but haven't been very successful. Any ideas on how to properly do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{align*}
X + \overbrace{\parbox{8em}{some text  \\ and some more}}{\text{written above}}=Y+Z
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `^` symbol between the two arguments of `\overbrace`. Hence, just replace

```
\overbrace{\parbox{8em}{some text  \\ and some more}}{\text{written above}}
```

with

```
\overbrace{\parbox{8em}{some text  \\ and some more}}^{\text{written above}}
```

---

Here's a screenshot that shows the results of incorrect and correct usage of `\overbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
Incorrect
\[
X + \overbrace{\parbox{8em}{some text  \\ and some more}}{\text{written above}}=Y+Z
\]

Correct
\[
X + \overbrace{\parbox{8em}{some text  \\ and some more}}^{\text{written above}}=Y+Z
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pbox`, the \overbrace would fit better the paragraph size:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{align*}
X + \overbrace{\pbox{8em}{some text \\ and some more}}^{\text{written above}}=Y+Z
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]